# <a4j:commandLink> Action is executed only one time?

Tags: java, richfaces, jsf-1.2, jboss-4.0.x

I have the following code working, the objective is simple: execute the action, then open the modalpanel, it's working, but the action is only executed one time, after that the modalpanel is opened without the action being executed.

```
<h:form>
  <ui:repeat id="al11" var="albumslistvalue1" 
  value="#{AlbumDetailBean.getAlbumImagesList()}">
    <a4j:commandLink id="link" action="#{AlbumDetailBean.mudaIdatual()}" 
    reRender="link, panel" 
    oncomplete="javascript:#{rich:component('panel')}.show();">
      <f:param value="#{albumslistvalue1.id}" name="idfotoatual"/>
      <h:graphicImage id="image" 
      url="#{albumslistvalue1.albumimagename}"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>
  </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

I'm stuck on this for a long time, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or maybe forgetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common cause of this is because there are some validation errors on your page, to get them all you can use `h:message` and `h:messages` to see if there are validation errors.

You can check this thread for detailed info, specially item number #4. [Jsf Action not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183)

Comment: No messages are shown, and I checked every item on that thread, still not working